# R: calling function multiple times and outputting unique files

Tags: r

I would like to run the function below 100 times and output 100 files:

```
myFunction <- function(val) {
    x <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3) 
    y <- x + val
    write.table(y, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, "file_val.txt")
    }
```

For example:

```
myFunction(5)  #outputs file_val.txt for val = 5
myFunction(6)  #outputs file_val.txt for val = 6
myFunction(7)  #outputs file_val.txt for val = 7
...
myFunction(105)  #outputs file_val.txt for val = 105
```

However, I would like to automate this process (e.g., with a loop) and generate 100 separate files with unique identifying names (`file_5.txt, file_6.txt, file_7.txt, ... , file_105.txt`).

Is there a way I can achieve this?  I've been experimenting with `seq()` and `rep()`.  Related post: [Write output of R loop to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292880/write-output-of-r-loop-to-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo can use `sprintf()`and `lapply()` for this:

```
x <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3) 

myFunction <- function(val) {
  y <- x + val
  write.table(y, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sprintf("file_%s.txt", val)
}

lapply(1:100, myFunction )
```